# Tracking a specific edge as it moves throughout space

Tags: python, opencv

I have an object I need to track. The object moves up and back mostly in a straight line, however, sometimes the object moves to the left. I need to track that left movement and convert the distance of the move to a measurement.

Image 1:

[image: Original Image]

The object moves up and down the, however wanders to the left.

Image 2:

[image: Showing object travel]

I was thinking to find an edge I wanted to track, then draw a line from that edge to a normal point. The line is measured in pixels and a real distance inferred.

**My question is**, how to track that edge circle (in my case is 1049, 390) when it moves up and back and still keep a right angle line for the measurement?

Note: in my case i've had to crop the image because the image quality is poor, many grainy lines. The cv.cornerHarris() method pics up those grainy lines as edges/contours, of which there are many.

Image 3:

[image: Masked image]

Am I on the right track or need a different approach?

Below is a mod of some code I found on Stack. The distance part im not concerned about, just tracking the movement of the selected edge.

```
    import cv2 as cv
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
    
    image = cv.imread('image_mask.jpg')
    object_width_known_a = .1445
    object_width_known_b = .0849
    object_width_known_x = .0849
    
    object_height = 1
    img_shape_x = image.shape[1]
    img_shape_y = image.shape[0]
    x_centre = round(img_shape_x/2)
    y_centre = round(img_shape_y/2)
    
    
    # Find Corners
    def find_centroids(dst):
        ret, dst = cv.threshold(dst, 0.02 * dst.max(), 255, 0)
        dst = np.uint8(dst)
    
        # find centroids
        ret, labels, stats, centroids = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(dst)
    
        # define the criteria to stop and refine the corners
        criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 1)
        corners = cv.cornerSubPix(gray, np.float32(centroids[1:]), (5, 5), (-1, -1), criteria)
        return corners
    
    gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # gray = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 1)  # Gaussian filter with a 7 x 7 kernel,
    
    gray = np.float32(gray)
    dst = cv.cornerHarris(gray, 4, 3, 0.065)
    
    # Get coordinates of the corners.
    corners = find_centroids(dst)
    
    
    for i in range(10, len(corners)):
        print("Pixels found for this object are:", corners[i])
        image[dst > 0.1 * dst.max()] = [0, 0, 255]
        cv.circle(image, (int(corners[i, 0]), int(corners[i, 1])), 5, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    
    
    for corner in corners:
        image[int(corner[1]), int(corner[0])] = [0, 0, 255]
        line_x = cv.line(image, (x_centre, 0), (x_centre, x_centre), (255, 0, 0), 1)
        line_y = cv.line(image, (1049, 390), (x_centre, 390), (255, 0, 0), 1)
        line_ang = cv.line(image, (1049, 390), (x_centre, x_centre), (0, 0, 255), 1)
    
    
    d = (dist.euclidean((1049, 390), (x_centre, x_centre)))
    y_px_dist = (dist.euclidean((1049, 390), (x_centre, 390)))
    print(y_px_dist)
    dist_to_edge = d / object_width_known_x
    print(dist_to_edge, 'm')
    
    a = (dist.euclidean((657, 540), (720, 540)))
    b = (dist.euclidean((650, 400), (687, 400)))
    x = (dist.euclidean((1049, 390), (x_centre, 390)))
    
    object_width_a = a
    object_width_b = b
    object_width_x = x
    
    pixels_per_metric_a = object_width_a / object_width_known_a  # y pixels per 500mm
    pixels_per_metric_b = object_width_b / object_width_known_b
    pixels_per_metric_x = object_width_x / object_width_known_x
    
    print(a, '=', pixels_per_metric_a, 'mm')
    print(b, '=', pixels_per_metric_b, 'mm')
    print(x, '=', pixels_per_metric_x, 'mm')
    
    a = len(corners)
    print("Number of corners found:", a)
    
    # List to store pixel difference.
    distance_pixel = []
    
    # List to store mm distance.
    distance_mm = []
    
    P1 = corners[0]
    P2 = corners[1]
    P3 = corners[2]
    P4 = corners[3]
    
    P1P2 = cv.norm(P2 - P1)
    P1P3 = cv.norm(P3 - P1)
    P2P4 = cv.norm(P4 - P2)
    P3P4 = cv.norm(P4 - P3)
    
    pixelsPerMetric_width1 = P1P2 / object_width_a
    pixelsPerMetric_width2 = P3P4 / object_width_a
    pixelsPerMetric_height1 = P1P3 / object_height
    pixelsPerMetric_height2 = P2P4 / object_height
    
    # Average of PixelsPerMetric
    pixelsPerMetric_avg = pixelsPerMetric_width1 + pixelsPerMetric_width2 + pixelsPerMetric_height1 + pixelsPerMetric_height2
    
    pixelsPerMetric = pixelsPerMetric_avg / 4
    # print(pixelsPerMetric)
    P1P2_mm = P1P2 / pixelsPerMetric
    P1P3_mm = P1P3 / pixelsPerMetric
    P2P4_mm = P2P4 / pixelsPerMetric
    P3P4_mm = P3P4 / pixelsPerMetric
    
    distance_mm.append(P1P2_mm)
    distance_mm.append(P1P3_mm)
    distance_mm.append(P2P4_mm)
    distance_mm.append(P3P4_mm)
    
    distance_pixel.append(P1P2)
    distance_pixel.append(P1P3)
    distance_pixel.append(P2P4)
    distance_pixel.append(P3P4)
    
    # print(distance_pixel)
    # print(distance_mm)
    
    cv.imshow('image', image)
    cv.waitKey(0)e
```

**EDIT -------------------------------**

Ive edited the question with another image. Ive overlaid the image with the coordinates of the same spot (manually, the left images same as 2nd from the left). As you can see, the coords change in each image as the object moves. I was thinking to add an ID to the cornerHarris() corner coords but then the question is, how to find the coords of that corner when it moves.

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sbBz.jpg)

Code for the new image:

```
    image = cv.imread('./image_masks/image_mask.jpg')

    object_height = 1
    img_shape_x = image.shape[1]
    img_shape_y = image.shape[0]
    x_centre = round(img_shape_x / 2)
    y_centre = round(img_shape_y / 2)

    gray_img = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray_img, 50, 0.06, 10)
    # kernel = np.ones((7,7), np.uint8)
    # corners = cv.dilate(corners, kernel, iterations=2)
    corners = np.int0(corners)

    for i in corners:
        x, y = i.ravel()
        cv.circle(image, (x, y), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
        print(x,y)

    line_x = cv.line(image, (x_centre, 0), (x_centre, x_centre), (255, 0, 
    0), 1)

    line_y2 = cv.line(image, (1028, 490), (x_centre, 390), (0, 255, 255), 
    1)
      d2 = (dist.euclidean((1080, 593), (x_centre, x_centre)))
      line_y5 = cv.line(image, (1050, 540), (x_centre, 390), (0, 255, 
     255), 1)
     d5 = (dist.euclidean((1050, 540), (x_centre, x_centre)))
     line_y3 = cv.line(image, (1071, 476), (x_centre, 390), (0, 255, 
     255), 1)
     d3 = (dist.euclidean((1071, 476), (x_centre, x_centre)))
     line_y6 = cv.line(image, (1071, 451), (x_centre, 390), (0, 255, 
     255), 1)
     d6 = (dist.euclidean((1071, 451), (x_centre, x_centre)))
     line_y4 = cv.line(image, (1047, 405), (x_centre, 390), (0, 255, 
     255), 1)
     d4 = (dist.euclidean((1047, 405), (x_centre, x_centre)))

     line_y = cv.line(image, (x_centre, 0), (x_centre, x_centre), (255,
     0, 0), 1)

     #print(d2, d5, d3, d6, d4)

     cv.imshow('image', image)
     cv.waitKey(0)nter code here
```

Comment: image 1 and 2 are the same, just cropped differently, and one has stuff drawn on top of it. is that supposed to demonstrate movement?

Comment: yes, img 2 is to highlight the object and movement.

Comment: I'd recommend video where actual movement can be observed. if pictures, then such pictures where the full range of motion of the object can be seen (extreme points).

Comment: thanks.. I only have pictures. Ive edited the question with another image. Ive overlaid the image with the coordinates of the same spot. As you can see the coords change in each image.

Answer (score 0):

All the internet object tracking solutions assume that the object being track is very different from everything else in the frame, e.g. a bright red dot on a piece of paper. They do this to find the largest contours, a reference point, a reference object). Measuring distances between objects uses similar techniques. This assumption that is not mentioned (well, pyimagesearch.com does mention, way down the end of a blog that if the contours are too many, not distinct, than the technique will not work). Real world problems don't have bright red dots on a piece of paper for a reference.

The centroid tracking method, using indexing (I found), only work if the centroid is very close to the pervious, in the previous frame (a video). I my situation, using still images, and possibly slightly different pictures to pervious, the centroid technique did not work.

I my case, the solution was to use a combination of masking, thresholding and contours. This limited the number of contours found and framed the problem.

The lesson (an for anyone else), experimentation is the key, experimentation with as many techniques as possible. This is a solution or a combination of for your problem. Internet examples often shown a perfect scenario, they generally do not directly transfer to real world problems.

Experiment!